# Ligation without purifying insert

Tags: molecular-biology, cloning, purification, ligation

I am planning to insert a 45 bp sequence in a vector. After restricting my insert to create compatible sticky ends, I am finding no way to clean it up. Is there any way for cleaning this fragment after restriction or should I proceed without clean-up?

Comment: Proceeding without cleanup will reduce your efficiency but may still work. Have you tried purifying via gel extraction? A high density gel should allow you to separate the band to some degree.

Comment: Hi Joe, I can locate the band in high density gel, but would it be possible to extract 45bp sequence through gel extraction protocol?

Comment: I *think* so, though you may need to ensure you use a column designed specifically for small fragment retention. There are columns for purification of miRNAs, so I’d have thought there might be a column you could source which will do a similar thing for dsDNA, but I am guessing somewhat. I believe there are some old-school chemical techniques for precipitating away melted gel without needing a column too that you could try. You could then concentrate with a rotorvap or heatblock.

Comment: “GeneClean” which involves adding powdered glass and potassium iodide solution to an agarose gel slice would work for this.  I believe QIAgen sells a matrix like this.  The glass is extremely fine, and has to be prepared by boiling in nitric acid.  Once upon a time there was a company named Bio 101 that sold a product named GeneClean, but they may have been bought by somebody else.  For unknown reasons, nucleic acids will bind to glass in the presence of a chaotrope.

Comment: A much simpler way to insert sequences that are really small is to order the DNA as oligos and anneal the complementary oligos such that they have compatible overhangs with the overhangs from  your restriction digest

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for your comments guys. I tried purifying using PCR purification kit. I could recover 120 ng of purified fragment from 500 ng. It is ok for my further work.

Comment: That's not too bad for a fragment of this size, the efficiency of the column kits (actually almost all DNA preps) goes down with decreasing size. If you wanted higher efficiency you could use a magnetic bead based kit such as Dynabeads or  AMPure XP ($$$, but the best).